# How to capture mouse movement for the whole window in opencv python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, opencv3.0, roi

I know and have seen tons of documentations explaining about how to capture mouse movement within a given window using mouseclick events in opencv. What I want to know is that if is there a way to capture mouse movements (x,y co-ordinates) for the entire screen of my system.

Any link, documentation or code snippet will be really helpful to proceed me with the same.

Comment: not with OpenCV. Use a proper GUI library

Comment: Any suggestions with the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your OS, you can do that with `pyautogui` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import pyautogui

for i in range(10):
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    print(f'Mouse position: x={x}, y={y}')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: On **macOS**, you *may* need to double coordinates because of some pixel doubling thing I don't understand too well.